# Cannot add a value to a table, error being thrown on a seemingly unrelated table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I am trying to add a value in my checkoutItems table, in the checkoutItems repository I use this method:

```
public async Task AddItemAsync(unitItem item, int amount, string selectedOptions)
   {
       var checkoutItem = await _appDbContext.CheckoutItems.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.unitItem.unitItemId == item.unitItemId && s.CheckoutId == _checkout.CheckoutId);

     if (checkoutItem == null)
     {
         checkoutItem = new CheckoutItem
         {
           CheckoutId = _checkout.CheckoutId,
           unitItem = item,
           Amount = 1,
           selectedOptions = selectedOptions
         };

         await _appDbContext.CheckoutItems.AddAsync(checkoutItem);
      }
      else
      {
          checkoutItem.Amount++;
      }
      await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
   }
```

But when this method tries to save the changes I get an error.

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

The issue is I am not trying to insert a value in the Categories table. When I check the SQL Server Profiler I see this code is trying to be executed:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Categories] ([CategoryId], [CategoryName], [Description])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2);
',N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(450),@p2 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=3,@p1=N'Food',@p2=N'Food served by our kitchen'
```

I have no idea where this is coming from. Everything was working fine until recently. I made no changes to the code and even restored the database to an earlier state to remove the changes (if any) I had made on the database, but no luck. What is causing this and how can I fix it.

The checkoutItems model looks like this:

```
public class CheckoutItem
{
   public int CheckoutItemId { get; set; }

   public unitItem unitItem { get; set; }

   public int Amount { get; set; }

   public string CheckoutId { get; set; }

   public string selectedOptions { get; set; }
}
```

And there are 2 degrees of separation between a checkoutItem and Category where an Item has a category.

Edit
If you comment out the line `unitItem = item,` in the add `AddItemAsync` method, seems to go around the issue. So the issue seems to be around adding the unitItem.

I still don't understand why it is adding a category when add a checkout item. The model for the unitItem looks like this:

```
public class unitItem
{
   [Required]
   public int unitItemId { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }

   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n2}")]
   public decimal Price { get; set; }

   public bool InStock { get; set; }

   public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

   public int CategoryId { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

   public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

   public string Description { get; set; }

   public string OptionFormData { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Any triggers involved?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Categories' ....", When adding value to unrelated table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561027/cannot-insert-explicit-value-for-identity-column-in-table-categories-w).  This is standard text for flagging question as duplicate. You should keep it all on one post

Comment: @jarlh I don't understand what you mean by triggers?

Comment: @Charlieface I asked that question, thought i would word it better, will delete the original post.

Comment: trigger is a tool which will lunch a event when ever it get 'trigger' , one of the most common use is when ever table a get insert new row, trigger happen, and automatically insert row into table b.

Comment: in this case I think the problem is you have a trigger which update/insert row into `Categories` when the function get call.

Comment: Where would such a trigger be and why is it only showing up now. I should also add that, I am also testing the same application using IIS server connected to the same database and it works fine running on the IIS Server but I get this error when using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

in your **unitItem** class add **Required** attribute to **CategoryId** not **Category**

```
public class unitItem
{
   [Required] //here
   public int CategoryId { get; set; }

   //[Required] //not here
   public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
   ....
```

then in **AddItemAsync** method; set **NULL** category object if **CategoryId** is bigger than zero

```
public async Task AddItemAsync(unitItem item, int amount, string selectedOptions)
{
   item.Category = null; //be sure item.CategoryId is not zero
   .....
```

Comment: If i try this, i get the same error but referencing the unitItems table

`SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'UnitItems' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.`

Comment: then your item object has value for PK column, try `item.unitItemId = 0` before add. or maybe your model is wrong

Comment: the model was working fine until recently, everything was working fine

Comment: I mean, your CheckoutItem class must have a field for unitItemId such as CategoryId with FK, then in your AddItemAsync method, you only set unitItemId property for checkoutItem object, not whole unitItem object. then your ORM will not try to create new records in the database without your control

Comment: but i need that reference, several parts of the application use that reference on data retrieval.

Comment: do not remove unitItem reference, it is normal to use in several parts of the application. when you create CheckoutItem object in your AddItemAsync method, you must only set unitItemId, not the whole item